# Background hangs under baseline with font-size 0.8em / small

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, background-image, baseline

I have a link icon which "hangs" under the baseline just because I use font-size 0.8em.

```css
a {
   padding-left: 6px;
   background: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAAKCAMAAACpO397AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAAZQTFRF/JoEAAAA0+PISwAAAA5JREFUeNpiYMAHAAIMAAAeAAHMILKLAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC") center left no-repeat;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.fs-09 {
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
.fs-08 {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
.fs-s {
    font-size: small;
}
```

```html
<a class="fs-09" href="#">Baseline</a>

<a class="fs-08" href="#">Baseline</a>

<a class="fs-s" href="#">Baseline</a>
```

[image]

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/4a49qmw0/

Tested and confirmed in recent Chrome and Firefox on Win8.

How can this be fixed? I want to continue using font-size 0.8em.

Comment: Can't replicate the issue, all yellow pipes are identically positioned on Firefox 35.0.1 for OS X.

Comment: Most likely due to pixel calculation of `center left` for the background image. If you are going to be this picky then you might as well set the x and y for the background image using units instead of `center left`

Comment: @Huangism Doesn't seem to work for 0.8em: http://jsfiddle.net/4a49qmw0/1/

Comment: @Martin you have to set them for each different font size